# Referencing another table with the same key value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding oracle SQL. so far i have this query and this doesnt work.

```
SELECT SUM(MDA.ASSIGNED_QTY * (SELECT MD.WEIGHT FROM MASTER_DRAWING MD WHERE MDA.HEAD_MARK = MD.HEAD_MARK)) TOTALWEIGHT
FROM MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED MDA
```

first of all i m just starting to learn oracle and i need suggestion on how to improve my code.

my table structure is like this

```
MASTER_DRAWING,
HEAD_MARK WEIGHT
HEAD1     20
HEAD2     30

MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED,
HEAD_MARK ASSIGNED_QTY
HEAD1     4
HEAD2     3
```

so my desired result would be,

```
HEAD1     80
HEAD2     90
```

would view suit better in this situation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the resultset as a view, then create a view based on the suggested answer :

```
CREATE VIEW v_totalweight
AS
SELECT md.HEAD_MARK,
  md.WEIGHT * mda.ASSIGNED_QTY AS totalweight
FROM MASTER_DRAWING md
JOIN MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED mda
ON md.HEAD_MARK = mda.HEAD_MARK
/
```

And query it,

```
SELECT * FROM v_totalweight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query

```
SELECT MDraw.HEAD_MARK,MDraw.[WEIGHT]*MDrawAss.ASSIGNED_QTY
FROM MASTER_DRAWING MDraw
LEFT JOIN MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED MDrawAss ON MDraw.HEAD_MARK=MDrawAss.HEAD_MARK
```